# Post request with multiple type of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've created below form, which when the submit button is pressed is suppose to make a post request and in the php add this to mysql. However i keep getting a `Post 500 (Internal Server Error)` when the post request is executed.

**form**

```
<form method="post" action="">

  <div class="reg_section personal_info">
    <input type="text" id="title" value="" placeholder="Campnavn" required="required" maxlength="25">


    <textarea name="textarea" id="description" value="" placeholder="Beskrivelse" required="required" minlength="100"></textarea>
    <div class="upload">
      <input type="file" name="upload" accept="image/*" id="image" />
      <span class="fileName">Select file..</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="submit" style="text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;"><input type="submit" id="insert" value="Tilføj"></span>
    <span class="submit" style="text-align: right; padding: 0 10px;"><input TYPE="button" value="Fortryd" onclick="div_hide();"></span>
  </div>

</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#insert").click(function(e) {

        var description = $('#description').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();

        var image = $("#image").serialize()


        $.post("insert.php",
        {
           title:  title,
           body: description,
           longitude: currentMarker.lng(),
           latitude: currentMarker.lat(),
           image: image
        }, function (data) {

        }).error(function () {

        });
    });
});
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php


      include('config.php');



      if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['latitude']))) {
        $target_dir = "image/";


        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $longitude = (float)$_POST['longitude'];
        $latitude = (float)$_POST['latitude'];
        $image = $_FILES['image'];

        $strSQL = $db->query("INSERT INTO camps (title, body, longitude, latitude, image) VALUES ('$title',  '$body', '$longitude','$latitude', '$image')");



      }



?>
```

Comment: I suggest you check your browser's network activity to see the exact request that is being made, and ensure the request path is correct and the values you expect are being passed.  Also, see if you can output the values from the server side prior to the DB call, I'm guessing that is where the error is occurring.

Comment: where did you take value of lang and lat ?
please add it your answer
and why you are have 2 submit button ?

Comment: the second button is just a close button. the lat and lang is saved to a global variable when use clicks on google map

Comment: I update my answer please check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this please, I change the `<form>` tag I add id and name, 
and change the submit button to normal button

```
<button type="button" onclick="postdata();" id="insert" >Tilføj</button>
```

after I define a onclick function to button...

**form**

```
        <form id="FormData" name="FormData">

          <div class="reg_section personal_info">
            <input type="text" id="title" value="" placeholder="Campnavn" required="required" maxlength="25">


            <textarea name="textarea" id="description" value="" placeholder="Beskrivelse" required="required" minlength="100"></textarea>
            <div class="upload">
              <input type="file" name="upload" accept="image/*" id="image" />
              <span class="fileName">Select file..</span>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div>
            <span class="submit" style="text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;">
<button type="button" onclick="postdata();" id="insert" >Tilføj</button>
    </span>
            <span class="submit" style="text-align: right; padding: 0 10px;">
<input TYPE="button" value="Fortryd" onclick="div_hide();"></span><br><br>
    <span id="result" style="color:#9B0E11; font-size:13px; font-weight:700"></span>
          </div>

        </form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postdata() {
    var description = $('#description').val();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var image = $("#image").serialize();

       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert.php',
            data: {
                desc: desctiption, 
                title: title, 
                image:image, 
                longitude: currentMarker.lng(),
                longitude: currentMarker.lat(),
                   },
            success: function (answer) {
                $("#result").html(answer) // if you wanna get response from insert.php
                $("#FormData")[0].reset(); // if you wanna reset form after submit
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

PS: in insert.php you add more one ")" in end of if statement you must delete it

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['latitude'])){
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you change?

Comment: @OscarJara thank you for warn I update all of codes and add explain